# Does Ubuntu 18.04 support ext3 format

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ext3

I've had to take a HDD out of my DLINK NAS and need to copy the data. I have a cradle that looks like this: 
https://www.amazon.ca/UGREEN-Converter-Adapter-2-5-3-5Inch-Supports/dp/B016JTH8FA/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=sata+to+usb+power&qid=1561347797&s=gateway&sr=8-3

When I plug it in, I only see a 524MB partition, and no data. It's a 2TB drive. Does Ubuntu not support ext3 format? Do I need to do anything additional?

Answer (score 4):

https://web.archive.org/web/20210725095058/https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/ch06s03.html#di-partition

ext2, ext3, ext4 are all supported.

However, was the drive taken out of the NAS that is part of a RAID? For instance, is it part of a striped RAID (0) opposed to a RAID 1 would be a complete mirror? If it is part of a striped RAID without the parity, it may not contain data that is supported because the writing of the blocks would contain partial fragments of data. Something similar to a bunch of corrupt data unless it is part of the same array as when the data was written to the drive.

EDIT:
A couple of things to add to my previous note. If there was any corruption of the RAID pair prior to you removing it and attempting to read it as a single drive, the corruption would follow both HDDs of the RAID 1 configuration depending on which one was considered the master drive. Is there any possibility that you have failed to mention here that the hard drive you are reading from was from a failed RAID 1 pair?

A couple of links for sites that are part of your multi-stage question that may lead you into understanding what options you have that are specific to DLINK: http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=65242.0 http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=58580.0 http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=41734.0

## ADDITIONAL UPDATE: (from another article on the DLINK website)

Some additional steps may be needed due to the way RAID writes data to the disk. Please see the link: http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=54559.0

In case the link no longer works, here are the steps that the original poster, ironcyborg, had posted. You may not be considering this a failed array, but the steps from reading from the drive shouldn't matter:

I'd like to share the procedure I used on Ubuntu 12.04 and ArchLinux to access data from a disk of a degraded RAID 1 created with a D-Link DNS-320L NAS.

The graphical way is really simple: you just need to

- install the mdadm package
  (sudo apt-get install mdadm on Ubuntu and Debian, sudo pacman -S mdadm on Arch)
- restart the PC
- connect the disk via SATA or USB dock
- three partitions show up on the file manager: the biggest one is the partition that contains your data.

The command-line procedure is a little more complicated:

- install the mdadm package
  (sudo apt-get install mdadm on Ubuntu and Debian, sudo pacman -S mdadm on Arch)
- connect the disk via SATA or USB dock
- run lsblk to find the partition that contains your data and write it down (e.g. sde2)
- use mdadm to assemble the RAID: sudo mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/[YOUR PARTITION]
- create a new mount directory for you disk: sudo mkdir /media/raiddisk
- mount you disk: sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raiddisk
- now your data is accessible and mounted in /mnt/raiddisk
  before removing your disk, remember to:
- unmount the disk: sudo umount /mnt/raiddisk
- unmount the RAID: sudo umount /dev/sd0
- stop the RAID: sudo mdadm -S /dev/md0

Comment: It was a RAID 1 configuration. Any idea why I'd only see the 524MB partition?

Comment: @Balldigy it maybe preferable to edit your answer itself to address issues raised in comments. Doing so would increase the value of your answer.

Comment: Moved comments to edit the original answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for following up, but none of these answer the one question I have. Why is it I can only see a 524MB partition on the drive? I've shown the caddy I'm using, and I'm on Ubuntu. It's not a failed RAID1, I can read the data when it's in the DNS320 device. I can't have that DNS on the same network as the new storage device, so I want to slave that HDD and copy it that way. Any other suggestions?

Comment: you can read the 524MB partition because that is the part that is presented when trying to read the data from the disk. See my update. You will probably need to have mdadm in order to read the data on the drive.